# Facebook feed dialog , post to wall , caption out off frame

Tags: ios, facebook

i am using newest Facebook SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

and trying use feed dialog to Post to wall , the caption are out off the dialog frame.

it missing some word so i can't read whole caption, like this:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/66oyf (sorry i can't post image on stack overflow yet since my reputation is too low.)

here is the code:

```
     NSMutableDictionary *param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [Utility getFBIconUrlHref], @"link",
                               [Utility getFBIconUrlSrc], @"picture",
                               name, @"name",
                               _bookName, @"caption",
                              @"description" , @"description", nil];

    [_fb dialog: @"feed"
    andParams: param
    andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: i found out this issue only happen at iPhone-protrait & upsideDown，landscape at iPhone works perfect , and iPad won't have this issue，could someone please give me some comment?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you want such a long caption- also I'm sure you can hack into the uiview settings in the facebook libraries and change stuff if you wanted- but bad idea, since then you can't upgrade the sdk, etc. The intention of the caption was to be a domain/web site, or a short tagline.

Comment: i solve this issue when i short the description , thx you.